# How to Group by and sum in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
 var SCount = new List<object>();
```

## First time Add DataTable dt1

DataSet ds = s.SelectProvider(Session["sender"], Provider, YearMonth);

```
                DateTime dt = new DateTime();
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    string code = string.Empty; 

                    foreach (DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        dt = Convert.ToDateTime(r["CDate"]);                             
                        SCount.Add(new { Mydate = dt.ToString("%d"), Mycount = ((480 - Convert.ToInt32(r["Minutes"])) / 30).ToString() }); 
                    } 
                }
```

## Second Time Add Through Object

```
         var kar= kd.GetCalender4HomePage(Id);
                    foreach (var i in kar)
                    {
                        dt = Convert.ToDateTime(i.EventDate);
                        if(YearMonth == dt.ToString("yyyy-MM"))
                            SCount.Add(new { Mydate = dt.ToString("%d"), Mycount = ((480 - Convert.ToInt32(i.ValueOne)) / 30).ToString() });
                    }
```

Result Is

```
          Mydate               |   MyCount
     ===========================================
             12                    30
             12                    10
             13                    11
```

But I need Result like

```
          Mydate               |   MyCount
     ===========================================
             12                    40
             13                    11


    var result = SCount.GroupBy(o => o.Mydate).Select(o => new { Date = o.Key, MyCount = o.Sum(s => s.Mycount) });
```

I tried. Its Come Error
      object' does not contain a definition for 'Mydate' and no extension method 'Mydate' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: At-least give it a try. Show some attempted code.

Comment: Could you help from my Updated Code

Comment: yeah that code won't work cz you are projecting a `List<object>`, I am not sure for what reason. Create a class with properties `Mydate` & `MyCount`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = SCount.GroupBy(o => o.Mydate)
                   .Select(o => new { Date = o.Key, MyCount = o.Sum(s=>s.Mycount) });
```

Comment: Date = o.Key, MyCount = o.Sum(s=>s.Mycount)   Error 2 Invalid expression term ','

Comment: @VictorEbe `select new` of couse

Comment: Now SCount.GroupBy(o => o.Mydate)                          Error 2 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Mydate' and no extension method 'Mydate' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @VictorEbe becase you have list of objects `var SCount = new List<object>();` replace `object` with special class

Comment: var SCount = new List<object>(); placed in same class

Comment: Could you help from my Updated Code